# Extracting name/value pairs with variable end of name from JSON during deserialization

Tags: java, json, deserialization, jira

Is it possible to use Jackson's ObjectMapper to create Java objects from JSON which contains names haven a knwon beginning ("customfield") and a variable ending (which is the ID of a databse in fact).
So in a JSON you can find something like this:

```
"customfield_10000":null
or
"customfield_10002":"hello"
or
"customfield_10005":["com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@1cc5ffd5[id=1,rapidViewId=1,state=ACTIVE,name=Sample Sprint 2,startDate=2017-11-30T02:29:06.805+01:00,endDate=2017-12-14T02:49:06.805+01:00,completeDate=<null>,sequence=1,goal=<null>]"]
```

These customfields are not part of any POJO, they just come with an event and I have to handle the incoming JSON.

I have to work with these fields so that I am not allowed to ignore them at all but it seems as if I have to handle them separately. ...I just don't know how.

Comment: Have you looked into the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation, which lets you specify which fields of the JSON you want Jackson to handle? http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html

Comment: Yes, but I don't want ignore them. I have to handle them but I don't have a fix name for these field because they have a variable ending.

Comment: In my experience, if you don't annotate any fields and just use the `JsonSerialize` and `JsonDeserialize` class-level annotations, Jackson will automatically parse and serialize all fields in your JSON blob for you